# If $2^n+1$ is prime, why must $n$ be a power of $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

A little bird told me that if $2^n+1$ is prime, then $n$ is a power of $2$. I tend not to trust talking birds, so I'm trying to verify that statement independently.

Suppose $n$ is not a power of $2$. Then $n = a \cdot 2^m$ for some $a$ not a power of $2$ and some integer $m$. This gives $2^n+1 = 2^{a \cdot 2^m}+1$. Now I suspect there's a way to factor that, but I don't see how. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: A proof of this fact is also given in Wikipedia article on [Fermat primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_prime#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers).

Comment: Neat. I didn't know it had a name.

Comment: Disproof: $2^0+1=2$ → $n=2^k=0$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213800

Comment: @xoxox: "where *n* is a nonnegative integer"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Hint**. For any odd natural number $a$, the polynomial $x+1$ divides $x^a+1$ evenly.

> In particular, we have $$ \frac{x^a+1}{x+1}=\frac{(-x)^a-1}{(-x)-1}=1-x+x^2-\cdots+ (-x)^{a-1}$$ by the [geometric sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series). In this case, specialize to $x=2^{2^{\large m}}$ and we have a nontrivial divisor.
>
>  (Also, $x^a+1\equiv(-1)^a+1\equiv-1+1\equiv0\mod x+1$ inside $\Bbb Z[ x]$ is pretty slick.)

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late post, but could you explain your answer a bit more for me. Did you mean to say, set $x = 2^m$ instead of $x = 2^{2^m}$

Comment: @TylerHilton No, I meant $x=2^{2^m}$ as I wrote. If $n=a2^m$ with $a$ odd, then this shows that $2^{2^m}+1$ divides $2^{a2^m}+1=2^n+1$, and hence $2^n+1$ is composite when $n$ is not a power of $2$.

Comment: @TylerHilton Every positive integer can be expressed as a power of 2 times an odd number. There is a law $(a^b)^c = a^(b \times c)$. Take any positive integer n. Now, $2^n + 1$ can be expressed as $(2^b)^c + 1$ where $b$ is a power of 2 and $c$ is an odd number. Since $c$ is odd, $(2^b) + 1$ is a factor of $(2^b)^c + 1$.