# Prove if, $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers

Prove, when $n$ is a positive integer, if $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

I did read some sort of proving on the web, but I could not understand it...

Any help?

And if possible, could the explanations be very clear?

Thank you guys :)

So, I've found this from somewhere:

Theorem. If $2^n−1$ is prime then $n$ is prime.

Proof. Suppose that $2^n−1$ is prime, and write $n=st $ where $s,t $ are positive integers. Since
$x^s−1=(x−1)(x^{s−1}+x^{s−2}+⋯+1)$ ,
we can substitute $x=2^t $ to see that $2^t−1$ is a factor of $2^n−1$. Since $2^n−1$ is prime there are only two possibilities,
$2^t−1=1$ or $2^t−1=2^n−1 $.
Therefore $t=1 $ or $t=n$. We have shown that the only possible factorisations of $n$ are $n×1$ and $1×n$. Hence, $n$ is prime.

However, I have a few questions:

1. how do you know  $x^s−1=(x−1)(x^{s−1}+x^{s−2}+⋯+1) $
2. why is$ 2^t−1 $a factor of $2^n−1$
3. how do you determine $2^t−1=1$or$2^t−1=2^n−1$from 'Since $2^n−1$ is prime'
4. 'the only possible factorisations of $n$ are$ n×1$ and $1×n$. '   how?
5. how did 'Hence, $n$ is prime' come out as result?

Comment: If $\exists p,q\in\mathbb N_{\neq 1} (n=pq)$, then $2^n-1=(2^p-1)(2^{n-p}+\cdots+1)$, contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** First, you'd need to know that $(a-b)\mid (a^n - b^n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Once you do that, consider the contrapositive (if $n$ is not prime, then $2^n - 1$ is not prime).

Comment: what doess the  ' ∣ '  represent?

Comment: Oh, my bad. $\mid$ represents "divides": $a\mid b$ means you can write $b = ak$, for some integer $k$.

Comment: No problem :)  So, a ∣ b means b/a ?

Comment: @amin It means $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer, except for $0\mid 0$.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. And how do you write the indices... all my indices keep being corrected automatically to become as such:   2^b becomes 2b...

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference , write between dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the formula for the sum of the terms of a geometric progression
find the sum of first $q-1$ terms of a G.P. with first term $1$ and common ratio $2^p$, and remember that the sum is an integer.