# Prove that if $p = 2^{m}+ 1$ is prime, then $m$ is a power of $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this proof on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers)

There I dont understand this part:
"Because $1 < 2^{r+1} < 2^{k+1}$
 it follows that  $2^{k+1}$  is not prime." How? Please explain

Comment: This question might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140804/if-2n1-is-prime-why-must-n-be-a-power-of-2

Answer (score 2):

In the previous line they showed that $2^r+1$ is a factor of $2^k+1$.  If $1<2^r+1<2^k+1$ then $2^k+1$ would have a positive factor other than $1$ and itself, so it would not be prime.