# Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be prime numbers. Find the number of ordered triplets such that $x^y + 1 = z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

One of the possible ordered triplets is (2,2,5).

However I am unable to disprove that there will never be another triplet of prime numbers satisfying that condition.
something like (x,y,z) = (2,y,z).
In this case, we will have the final result of the expressions as odd on both the sides of the equality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When $z$ is even, the only solution is when $z=2$, or $x^y=1$. This can only be possible if $x=1$ or $y=0$, so there is no solution.

When $z$ is odd, $x^y$ must be even, so $x$ must be even, which means $x=2$. However by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140804/if-2n1-is-prime-why-must-n-be-a-power-of-2), if $2^y+1$ is prime, $y$ must be a power of $2$. The only $y$ that satisfies this is $2$, so $(2,2,5)$ is the only solution.

Comment: A parallel observation (implicit in your reference to another post, but more generally true). If $y\gt 1$ is odd then the left-hand side has a factor $x+1$ and cannot be prime, so we must have $y=2$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Great observation!