# How to check the primality of $2^n + 1$?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

With [Mersenne Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), if $M = 2^n - 1$ is prime, $n$ is prime.

Is there a trick (may be similar to that of Mersenne) to check the primality of $2^n + 1$?

Comment: Checking $n$ is prime is quicker than checking $2^n-1$ is prime

Comment: Using a generalization of the sum of two cubes factorization $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$, one can show that if $n$ has any odd factors, $M$ is composite.  This forces $n$ to be $2^k$ for some $k$.  Of these, $M$ is known to be prime when $k=0,1,2,3,4$, and all other values that we are able to check are composite.  These numbers are called "Fermat Primes"

Comment: There is $F_n=2^{2^k}+1.$

Comment: @Henry it's not clear how that's relevant. Why would we be checking if $n$ is prime if the fact that it's prime is given?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the first line can be read as saying that one way to find some prime numbers is to find other primes of the form $2^n-1$.  It may not be what was intended

Comment: @Henry ok that makes much more sense now, thanks

Comment: That 1st part is just a way of saying "If n is *not* prime, $2^n - 1$ is also *not* prime".

Comment: I will just mention that the exponent has to be [power of two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/140804). You can find some information about the numbers of the form $F_k=2^{2^k}+1$ in the Wikipedia article [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). For example, you might be interested in [Pépin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test.

Comment: If $2^{2^n}+1$ is divisible by a prime $p$ then $2$ has order $2^{n+1} \pmod p$, hence $p-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.  That cuts down the search for prime factors considerably.  For instance, with $n=5$ we consider $2^{32}+1$ and only search for prime factors congruent to $1\pmod {64}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (which, granted, doesn't necessarily mean much), the best test is

> If $n=1,2,4,8$ or $16$, then $2^n+1$ is prime. Otherwise, probably not.

It is known (and not difficult to show) that $n$ must be a power of $2$, but apart from the five powers of $2$ mentioned above, no such primes are known.

Numbers of the form $2^{2^k}+1$ are known as Fermat numbers, and the Fermat numbers that are also primes are known as Fermat primes.

That being said, it wouldn't surprise me if number theorists have come up with efficient ways of checking the primality of Fermat numbers, like the Lucas–Lehmer test for Mersenne primes. It's just that they have yet to yield anything.

Answer (score 2):

Worth remarking:  If a prime $p$ divides $2^{2^n}+1$ then $2$ has order $2^{n+1}\pmod p$.  This implies that $2^{n+1}\,|\,p-1$, which cuts down the search considerably.

As an example, consider $n=5$.  To try to find a prime dividing $2^{32}+1$ we look for primes $p\equiv 1 \pmod {64}$.  You can disregard the Fermat primes in that list, as the Fermat numbers are relatively prime.  This leads you to try $641$ fairly quickly, and that factor works.

Comment: Works with $n=6$! I had to write a loop, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A deterministic test for Fermat numbers is [Pépin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test):

Let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ with $n > 0$, then
$F_n$ is prime if and only if $3^{(F_n-1)/2}\equiv-1\pmod{F_n}.$

Pépin's test is a special case of the [Solovay–Strassen primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test) base 3. In the general case for testing arbitrary odd numbers and arbitrary bases that test is probalistic.